# DocBook5 and html forms

Tags: xml, docbook, xslt

I cannot get html:forms to work with DocBook5.

Here is a demo book: http://www.filedropper.com/demobooktar

Steps to reproduce:

- From docbook I'm using http://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/files/docbook-xsl-ns/1.76.1/ just drop it into the created directory after unpacking the POC above (as hinted by universe.xml).
- edit universe.xml accordingly (fix the paths)
- run ./build.sh

In htdocs/demo/ you will see the output. xsltproc will leave the unmatched form elements in place, colored in red.

Please help, I don't know what I'm missing there. Any hints is appreciated, any to the point answer accepted. Thanks.

**Addendum**

The error message is

> Element form in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' encountered in section, but no template matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your customization layer (online-course.xsl):

```
<xsl:template match="html:*" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```